# Missing zero's in the minutes of a string

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function in PHP which should save a date time stamp in the database:

```
public function advanceLevel(){
    $aCurrentdate = getdate();            
    $sDate = $aCurrentdate['mday']."-".$aCurrentdate['mon']."-".$aCurrentdate['year']." ".$aCurrentdate['hours'].":".$aCurrentdate['minutes'];
    $aUserRecord = $this->fetchUserRecord($_SESSION['iRecordnumber']);
    $iNewLevel = $aUserRecord[0][5] + 1; 
    $_SESSION['userlevel'] = $iNewLevel;
    unset($_SESSION['aQuestions']);
    $this->sPdoQuery=("INSERT INTO `tbl_progress` (`iFK_iUseracount_ID`,`sProgress`,`sDate`) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['iRecordnumber']."','Naar level ".$iNewLevel."','".$sDate."')");
    $this->PdoSqlReturnTrue();        
    $this->sPdoQuery=("UPDATE `tbl_useraccounts` SET `iLevelStatus` = '".$iNewLevel."' WHERE `iUseraccounts_ID` = '".$_SESSION['iRecordnumber']."'");
    $this->PdoSqlReturnTrue(); 
    return;    
}
```

But the result in the MySQL database are date/time stamps without any leading or trailing zero's.
[A picture of the results and the database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACE5E.png)

Source http://php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You could also use the sql now() function and set your table to DateTime, instead of using the php date function. works for me!

Comment: Do apply @Jorn's logic in your code, it will definitely resolve your issue. 1) Change the datatype of `sDate` column to DATETIME 2) Make use of MySQL's `NOW()` function in the query.

Comment: @Jorn, thank you for the workaround. But it does not explain why it happens. And I am curios why it happens.

Comment: "seconds" Numeric representation of seconds 0 to 59
"minutes" Numeric representation of minutes 0 to 59
[from php.net ]

I guess if you have a trailing 0 it will get cut of, like 10, but when its 11 it is a valid value from the function.

with the date() function you can be more specific of the return values

Comment: Based on the screenshot you posted in the question, you need to modify the table structure a little bit. Change the `sDate`'s column data type of `varchar` to `timestamp`. Now, it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->sPdoQuery=(
"INSERT INTO tbl_progress (iFK_iUseracount_ID,sProgress,sDate) 
VALUES (
    '".$_SESSION['iRecordnumber']."',
    'Naar level ".$iNewLevel."',
    NOW()
)";
    $this->PdoSqlReturnTrue();

set your column type to TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: Thank Jorn. I changed it to your solution.